# Using selector on blocking ServerSocketChannel

Tags: java, nio

When and what is the usecase of having selector on blocking ServeSocketChannel? 
In general, how does selector works on blocking channels?

Comment: In general, it doesn't. Selectors are meant to be used with non-blocking IO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from [SelectableChannel javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel.html):

> A channel *must* be placed into non-blocking mode before being registered with a selector, and *may not* be returned to blocking mode until it has been deregistered.

See the javadoc for `register()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel.html#register(java.nio.channels.Selector,%20int)

`public final SelectionKey register(Selector sel, int ops)`

**Throws**:

```
    IllegalBlockingModeException - If this channel is in blocking mode
```

This is how `register()` looks like:

```
public final SelectionKey register(Selector sel, int ops,
                                   Object att)
    throws ClosedChannelException
{
    if (!isOpen())
        throw new ClosedChannelException();
    if ((ops & ~validOps()) != 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    synchronized (regLock) {
        if (blocking)
            throw new IllegalBlockingModeException();
...
```

Answer (score 2):

> When and what is the usecase of having selector on blocking `ServerSocketChannel`?

There isn't one. It isn't supported.

> In general, how does selector works on blocking channels?

It doesn't. When you try it you will get an `IllegalBlockingModeException`.